# I am able to update the state using action and reducer but on the component when I try to do onClick for the action it throws

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk

```
    ` import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
       import { connect } from 'react-redux';
        import { itemsFetchData } from '../actions/sidenavaction';

       class SideNavItem extends Component {
            componentDidMount() {
           this.props.fetchData('http:
           //58f5d2ccc9deb71200ceecef.mockapi.io/nav');
            }

          render() {    
          var Nest=function(par) {
                const numbers = par.itemized;
                const listItems = numbers.map((number) => <li key=
           {number.sid}>{number.svalue}</li>);
                return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>);
            };



             if (this.props.hasErrored) {
               return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
               }

           if (this.props.isLoading) {
        return <p>Loading…</p>;
              }

           return (
        <ul>{this.props.items.map((item) =>         
        <ul key={item.id} onClick={this.props.toggleDiv}><a href="#">
           {item.value}</a>
            {item.sub && <Nest itemized={item.sub} />}          
        </ul>               
        )}
        </ul>
            );          
          }
             }

        const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
     items: state.items,
     hasErrored: state.itemsHasErrored,
     isLoading: state.itemsIsLoading
           };
            };

         const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
               return {
             fetchData: (url) => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url)),
                toggleDiv: () => dispatch(toggleDiv())
            };
       };

              export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
        (SideNavItem);`
```

On the on Click function I am passing the toggleDiv action to props but on clicking the tag on my screen it throws error toggleDiv not defined.The state is also getting updated by the value which I want to pass using action and reducer
  (action)
              `export function toggleDiv(){
                return {
                type: 'TOGGLE_DIV'
                  };
                   }`

(reducer)
         `export function toggleDivReducer(state = { hidden: true}, action){
               switch(action.type) {

```
        case 'TOGGLE_DIV':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {hidden: !state.hidden});

            default:
            return state;

          }

           }`
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleDiv is not defined                                    Please explain .THANKSALOT

Comment: Are you missing `toggleDiv` in the import ?? `import { itemsFetchData } from '../actions/sidenavaction';` ??

Comment: Oh thanks will look into it

Comment: Thanks alot it works

Comment: @Panther One more thing how can I pass id and do e.preventdefault onClick

Comment: @Panther I have done onClick={this.props.toggleDiv.bind(this,item.id)} but also I want only the click event to fire for the tag on which I have clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only import `itemsFetchData` action but not `toggleDiv`, so when `mapDispatchToProps`, `toggleDiv` is not undefined

Comment: oh Thanks alot will look into it